# Azure - Not Redirecting to Default Page and showing "Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core'" Error

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have been working with a Project which is split into the following: 
(1) Client Application (HTML5, CSS3, JS / AngularJS) and 
(2) WebAPI.

It works fine locally, when I run the application, however, when I deployed the application to Azure and I attempt to access the client application, I get the below error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

When I type /index.html within the browser, the default page then loads correctly, however, I would like that the redirection happens automatically, without showing the error.

I have set the redirection to the default page in IIS as well, but it is not redirecting by default.

I was reading some of the other questions similar to this error, however, I do not even have a packages.config file since the Client application I have, is mostly a HTML5 / CSS and JS application.

Comment: Which one do you choose as your Web API, Core application(.NET Core) or Core application(.NET Framework). If you choose .NET Framework, please try to set DotNetOpenAuth.Core's copy local as true to see whether it helps.

Comment: @Jambor-MSFT - The Web API solution is running .NET Framework 4.5.2  but this issue is being triggered from my client application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution from a Microsoft Azure support agent. When re-deploying the site with the the option "Remove additional files at destination", this is now working.

This may be because of some default code Azure Websites is trying to run as a default page, so by checking that option, any previous code is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not even have a packages.config file

As I know, The error message shows missing/mismatching a .NET framework assembly. Based on your description, your application does not have packages.config. Which template do you choose when creating your client application in Visual Studio? Do you use other IDE for developing?

> When I type /index.html within the browser, the default page then loads correctly, however, I would like that the redirection happens automatically, without showing the error.

May be the index.html does not use the assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.Core", so it will work fine. But it does not mean your application will work without any error. Does your application works well on your local? Could you find the assembly on your local? If publish to Azure, do you find this assembly on Azure Web app server?

Comment: I created an ASP.NET Empty Web Site for that solution. None of the project should be dependent on any .NET assemblies, since all I am using within it is HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript. Application works well locally, and also loads the index.html page automatically. I hope this answers all of your questions.