# Azure - WebAPI unable to connect to Azure DB, Error: The system cannot find the file specified [SqlException]

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, asp.net-web-api2

I have an application, split into three sections which are all hosted on Azure:
  (1) Client Application (HTML5, CSS3, JS),
(2) Web API,
 (3) SQL Server Database Instance.

I have all these working on localhost, after enabling the client IP in the database's firewall settings on Azure, however, when deploying the application, I am getting the following error from the Web API:

> [Win32Exception]: The system cannot find the file specified
>   [SqlException]: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

I tried to check the firewall settings on Azure, and I have the "Allow access to Azure Services" which I am guessing means that the WebAPI Service should have access to the database.

[image: Firewall Access]

I have just successfully connected via SQL Server Management Studio with the same credentials within the web.config as well.

Is there something else I should check?

Comment: Do you use ASP.Net Identity for Authentication and Authorization?

Comment: @Win - Yes I do, I should have an .mdf file in the App_Data for that as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you use ASP.Net Identity and you have database inside App_Data, you will have to create that database in SQL Azure too.

*You cannot use LocalDb (those located inside App_Data folder) in Azure. Normally, LocalDb is for development only.*

***FYI:*** In ASP.Net Identity, if you happen to have different connection string name than **DefaultConnection**, you will have to rename it too.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try to change that and try again. Having said that, I have another endpoint, which connects to the Azure DB (not the Identity DB), which shows the same error. What's the issue there? Will it be automatically fixed once I fix the original issue?

Comment: Exception did not say what connection string; I believe it is related to LocalDb. It might solve the entire problem, once you create those LocalDbs in SQL Azure. In your case, you will finally end up with multiple connection strings in web.config - one for each database.

Comment: You were right, once I fixed this, everything else worked. Given you seem to be an expert on this topic, I still have an Azure related issue, maybe you know what's wrong with this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331133/azure-not-redirecting-to-default-page-and-showing-could-not-load-file-or-asse.